# How to access AVD (Android Virtual Device) internal storage

Tags: android, storage, virtual, android-virtual-device, internals

Does anyone know how to access AVD (Android Virtual Device) Internal Storage? I see that there's an icon in AVD manager to access the storage but its been grayed out.

[image]

I also checked in device settings but no clue... any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start the emulator you should be able to view something like this
If you don't have the device file explorer tab type Ctrl+Shift+A and type device file explorer in the box that pops up
[image: list of files on an emulated device]

Comment: Bless you brother... Apparently my Android studio was not configured for android framework and the device file explorer was missing ... Thanks